# ThreadPool and methods with while(true) loops?

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming

ThreadPool utilizes recycling of threads for optimal performance over using multiple of the Thread class. However, how does this apply to processing methods with while loops inside of the ThreadPool?

As an example, if we were to apply a thread in the ThreadPool to a client that has connected to a TCP server, that client would need a while loop to keep checking for incoming data. The loop can be exited to disconnect the client, but only if the server closes or if the client demands a disconnection.

If that is the case, then how would having a ThreadPool help when masses of clients connect? Either way the same amount of memory is used if the clients stay connected. If they stay connected, then the threads cannot be recycled. If so, then ThreadPool would not help much until a client disconnects and opens up a thread to recycle.

On the other hand it was suggested to me to use the Network.BeginReceive and NetworkStream.EndReceive asynchronous methods to avoid threads all together to save RAM usage and CPU usage. Is this true or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Slow blocking codes can cause poor performances both on the client-side as well as server-side. You can run slow work on a separate thread and that might work well enough on the client-side but may not help on the server-side. Having blocking methods in the server can diminish the overall performance of the server because it can lead to a situation where your server has a large no of threads running and all blocked. So, even simple request might end up taking a long time. It is better to use asynchronous APIs if they are available for slow running tasks just like the situation you are in. (Note: even if the asynchronous operations are not available, you can implement one by implementing a custom awaiter class) This is better for the clients as well as servers. The main point of asynchronous code is to reduce the no of threads. Because servers can have larger no of requests in progress simultaneously because reducing no of threads to handle a particular no of clients can improve scalability.

If you dont need to have more control over the threads  or the thread-pool you can go with asynchronous approach.

Also, each thread takes 1 MB space on the heap. So, asynchronous methods will definitely help reduce memory usage. However, I think the nature of the work you have described here is going to take pretty much the same amount of time in multi-threaded as well as asynchronous approach.

Comment: 'your server has a large no of threads running and all blocked. So, even simple request might end up taking a long time' - what??

Comment: Depends on how you're defining "blocked." If you're talking about NoDelay for TcpClient, I have that set to true to avoid blocking.

Comment: Blocking - any long running operation

Comment: The requests shouldn't take much time, although the memory usage would sky rocket. Since 1024 clients would be a GB of memory.

Answer (score 3):

> Either way the same amount of memory is used if the clients stay
>   connected.

So far this is true. It's up to your app to decide how much state it needs to keep per client.

> If they stay connected, then the threads cannot be recycled. If so,
>   then ThreadPool would not help much until a client disconnects and
>   opens up a thread to recycle.

This is untrue, because it assumes that all interesting operations performed by these threads are synchronous. This is a naive mode of operation, and in fact real world code is asynchronous: a thread makes a call to request an action and is then free to do other things. When a result is made available as a result of that action, some thread looking for other things to do will run the code that acts on the result.

> On the other hand it was suggested to me to use the
>   Network.BeginReceive and NetworkStream.EndReceive asynchronous methods
>   to avoid threads all together to save RAM usage and CPU usage. Is this
>   true or not?

As explained above, async methods like these will allow you to service a potentially very large number of clients with only a small number of worker threads -- but by itself it will do nothing to either help or hurt the memory situation.